# If I buy a super off-peak ticket, can I travel on a off-peak train and pay the difference?

Tags: uk, trains, national-rail, upgrades, trainline

So I always try and buy the cheapest, off peak ticket - i.e super-off-peak.

Sitting here at my desk on a long Thursday, I really want to get that earlier train which is "normal" off peak - but alas, I bought a super off peak which means I need to hold off for another hour.

The difference between the tickets is only £7 - a price I am willing to pay to get into my lovely bed on the other side of the county and start my weekend. So the question is:

**Would I be able to get that slightly earlier train and pay the difference?**

Or would I have to buy a new ticket (obviously I'm aware I could refund the old one, but that would make the upgrade a total of £17 more after you take the admin fee).

---

Specifics:

- Padding - Cheltenham Spa
- Super off peak single - valid only changing at or passing through Stroud (but I often get the return version)
- Mobile ticket - bought via TheTrainLine
- Usually a GWR train

Comment: I was about to write an answer involving a simple procedure at a ticket office, but since you've specified you have a mobile ticket I don't think this is possible (unless you can get them to sell you an excess for a mobile ticket at a ticket office). With a paper ticket it would be possible with no additional charge/admin fee over the fare difference. Paper tickets also cost no more than mobile tickets. Paper tickets may be boring and old-fashioned but they maximise your rights.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer appears to be **yes** as long as you do so before boarding the train (otherwise you'll be travelling with an invalid ticket).

The National Rail [website](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46590.aspx) about Off-Peak and Super Off-Peak ticket terms and conditions says:

> **Changing the time or date of travel**
>
> If you wish to change your time of travel or class of the ticket, you
>   can pay the difference between the cost of the ticket held and the
>   cost of the ticket that is most appropriate for the journey you need
>   to make.
>
> In many cases, if you are still travelling at a time when your ticket
>   is not restricted, no additional fare is payable.
>
> If you wish to change the date of travel, or the origin or destination
>   of your ticket, it may be necessary to buy a new ticket and apply for
>   a refund on your existing ticket.

---

**Update**:

If you have an account it seems that you can do it online, see GWR's [Changing your ticket](https://www.gwr.com/help-and-support/changing-your-ticket). Otherwise at the station.

But there is also a £10 administration fee.

Comment: The administration fee is only for refunds, right?

Comment: @Mast the GWR link I posted says "Super Off-Peak, Off-Peak and Anytime tickets can be changed for a charge of £10 each, plus postal fees if applicable; if you bought online, or with our app, you’ll need to claim a refund and buy a new ticket." This follows the paragraph about "Advance" tickets, so it is not about that type.

Comment: Ah, right. GWR does say so indeed, if you look at the National Rail page it only talks about fees in case of refunds.

Comment: @weatherVane Please see the answer provided by RailPerson below regarding not needing to change the ticket before boarding the train and let me know if you think it would be unfair for me to accept that answer instead? I'm afraid I should have waited a few more hours so apologise

Comment: You can accept what you like, but I would say that if you board a train without a valid ticket, then when challenged you can say "I want to change it" or "I want to buy one." One is required to have a valid ticket when boarding a train, unless one could not be obtained at the station.

Comment: The National Rail Conditions of Travel linked by @RailPerson goes on to say in the next section that some train companies may charge a penalty if *10.2.3. You travel on a train service at a time when your Ticket is not valid.* Section 9.5 which was referred to does not say **on the train** but simply "charged the difference", in other words can be upgraded.

Comment: Going further, most of that post is a rant about customer service. If it were permissible to board a train without a valid ticket and then buy one when asked, then nobody would bother buying a ticket first (some with the hope that they won't be checked). Apart from buses, I have only ever used one mass transit system that didn't require a ticket to be held when boarding: the BA Heathrow-Glasgow shuttle in the days before heightened security. One could board 5 minutes before departure and buy the ticket after take-off. It was literally an air bus.

Answer (score 6):

According to https://www.railforums.co.uk/threads/railuk-fares-ticketing-guide-section-4-excesses-upgrades-supplements.70374/#post-1185795 yes you can, and there is no penalty for doing so on-board.

Note that for a return ticket, the price charged for the excess is the full difference between the original return ticket and the return ticket you are excessing to (unlike a change of route excess where you can excess half of the return ticket for half the difference in price). In some cases it may be cheaper to buy a new single ticket than to excess a return.

Comment: That link says specifically "if there is no opertunity to pay before boarding" which usually means that you need to have gotten on the train at a station with no working ticket machine or office

Comment: also, good luck getting past the Paddington barrier staff with anything they even *think* might be wrong

Comment: @AakashM Huh, in my experience the Paddington barrier staff barely glance at the ticket and just let almost everybody though.

Comment: "If bought on board where there was opportunity to pay before boarding: As above: there is no penalty on board with this type of excess."

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what others have said, there is no administration fee to pay to obtain an excess for a flexible but time-restricted ticket. That would only apply if you held an Advance ticket (i.e. fixed to one or more specific trains) and wished to travel on a different train to that which you had booked.

Indeed, if it were not for the fact that Paddington station has ticket barriers on almost all platforms, then you would perfectly well be entitled to get the excess on-board the train - regardless of previous ticketing opportunities. This right is given by Condition 9.5 of the [National Rail Conditions of Travel](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/National%20Rail%20Conditions%20of%20Travel.pdf).

So in your case you should be charged the difference to the £44.10 [Off-Peak Single route "via Stroud"](http://www.brfares.com/#faredetail?orig=PAD&dest=CNM&grpo=1072&rte=807&tkt=SVS) if that's the one that is valid at the time you want to travel. So that would be £11.50 assuming you don't hold a relevant Railcard.

In practice I agree that many ticket office staff will claim that this is not possible due to a variety of spurious excuses, such as you having bought the ticket from another retailer, the fact that you bought it online, or the fact that it is a non-paper ticket. Some may even claim that you can't obtain an excess for time restrictions *at all*! A few of these reasons may be *physically* true (i.e. the clerk would get in trouble with their manager if they sold the excess contrary to internal company policies) but none are legally valid reasons to refuse to sell you the excess *and* to refuse to let you travel.

If you do, therefore, wish to travel during a time your Super Off-Peak ticket isn't valid, and you are unable to extract the required excess from a ticket office, I would make sure to have some kind of record of this (e.g. covert audio recording - contrary to popular myth this is *not* illegal in any way, even if some may find it discourteous). Then pay whatever they claim it is you need to pay, and raise a complaint afterwards seeking to recover the overpaid amount (and escalate this as required).

It's shambolic and unacceptable that there are cases where passengers have to be out of pocket to exercise rights the industry has chosen to give them, but poor training or misinformation is rife across the industry and the only recourse, in some cases, is to ultimately resort to the County Court. Unfortunately.

Comment: Paddington doesn't have ticket barriers on platforms 8 and 9.

Comment: "*if it were not for the fact that Paddington station has ticket barriers on almost all platforms, then you would perfectly well be entitled to get the excess on-board the train*" Is this accurate? 6.1 states "You must have a valid Ticket to travel **before you board a train where there was the opportunity to buy one**"

Comment: @Muzer the cheltnham/swansea trains which are the ones I need to get in order to get to my destination seem to not have a set platform, even getting the exact same train one week to the next, sometimes there are barriers

Comment: Also, yes I do have a rail card, hence the difference between my number and the one on the answer, idea still holds I believe!

Comment: @Michael I can see why, if taken on its own, Condition 6.1 would appear to make it impermissible, or perhaps even illegal, to board without the excess where you had the opportunity to obtain it (and this is assuming that is the case - it's by no means guaranteed by the presence of a ticket office, as discussed in my answer!). However, you have to consider Condition 6.1 in the context of the NRCoT as a whole. In particular Condition 9.5 sets out the penalties for various types of ticketing mis-deeds. It specifically states the penalty for boarding with an invalid time-restricted ticket is 1/2

Comment: @Michael 2/2 nothing beyond having to pay the relevant excess. So even if we consider it an impermissible act, if you do do it, there is no penalty for doing so. You simply have to pay what you would have paid to begin with.

Comment: @Weather Vane I can't reply to your comment on the same thread. The fact that the NRCoT creates potential revenue protection issues for the train operators bears no relevance to passengers' rights. Penalty Fares do _not_ apply for 'breach' of time restrictions, in any case - NRCoT 9.5 explicitly say that the situation is regularised by an excess fare. In the event of any contradiction in terms as you are suggesting, [Section 69](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/15/section/69/enacted) of the Consumer Rights Act 2015 means that the more favourable meaning prevails (i.e. no Penalty Fare)

Comment: @RailPerson but section 9 also states that you may not board a train without a valid ticket: *9.1. Travelling without a valid Ticket (which includes, where relevant, any supporting documentation such as a Railcard), or being unable to present them when asked is a serious matter. Condition 6 sets out the only circumstances where you may board a train without a valid Ticket.* But condition 6 does not list wishing to upgrade a ticket as a valid reason. Section 9.5 is quite clear: is says you may upgrade your ticket, which means you don't have to throw it away and buy another.

Comment: @RailPerson  ... so, if the station staff will not upgrade your ticket, then you have a valid reason to board the train: a ticket was not obtainable at the station.

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree with your interpretation there, but agree that it is never a bad idea to _try_ to obtain the excess at the station - if nothing else to avoid potential disputes on-board the train. But with any non-paper ticket that is likely to be a very difficult exercise and so I just wanted to make the OP aware that they needn't wait the extra hour for fear of having to fork out for a brand new ticket (without recourse).